# Java Spring return redirect not working

Tags: java, spring, redirect

I have 2 function in controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/member-login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String loginPage() {
    if (isCurrentAuthenticationAnonymous()) {
        return "member_login";
    } else {
        return "member_profile";
    }
}
```

and

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/update/{resetID}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String update(ModelMap model, @PathVariable String resetID) {
    if (resetID != null) {
        return "redirect:member-login"
    } else {
        return "update"
    }
}
```

After my update action success, it should return to domain/member-login,
however, it currently return as domain/update/member-login.

Does anyone faces this issue before?

Comment: Which works as expected. When using redirect it creates a URL for the client to redirect to. YOu haven't provided a leading `/` so it will be a relative redirect (of the current URL). If you don't want that prefix with `/` and give the full path to redirect to.

Comment: I see! Thanks much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change return to

`return "redirect:/member-login"`

if your controller also having `@RequestMapping` anotation then provide its value also as :

`return "redirect:/controller's value/member-login"`